# Telerik Calendar doesn't appear

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, telerik

I have this (copied from the examples)...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp" x:Class="MyApp.MainPage" xmlns:telerikInput="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Input;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Input">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Padding="5">
            <Label Text="Select a view mode" />
            <Picker x:Name="viewModePicker" />
        </StackLayout>
        <telerikInput:RadCalendar x:Name="calendar" NativeControlLoaded="CalendarLoaded" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

And...

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            calendar.DisplayDate = new DateTime(2017, 4, 12);

            viewModePicker.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CalendarViewMode));
            viewModePicker.SelectedItem = CalendarViewMode.Day;
            viewModePicker.SelectedIndexChanged += ViewModeChanged;
        }

        private void ViewModeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            calendar.TrySetViewMode((CalendarViewMode)viewModePicker.SelectedItem);
        }

        private void CalendarLoaded(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            calendar.TrySetViewMode((CalendarViewMode)viewModePicker.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
```

Everything works, including the calendar instance existing, except I can't see it! I'm using an iOS app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled the DLLs from the Telerik Nuget server. Must have missed something, and I didn't realise that one can log on to their server using one's regular Telerik website credentials.

This resulted in the calendar appearing on my iPhone but not in the simulator. I copied my solution over to Mac OS and used Visual Studio Mac to build and deploy and now the calendar appears in the simulator too.

Also, the build and deploy time seems about twice as fast. Was using Windows on Parallels before, though.

Answer (score 1):

This rendered fine for me:

`StartPage.xaml.cs`

```
using System;
using Telerik.XamarinForms.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TelerikXamarinApp1
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class StartPage : ContentPage
    {
        public StartPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            calendar.DisplayDate = new DateTime(2017, 4, 12);

            viewModePicker.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(CalendarViewMode));
            viewModePicker.SelectedItem = CalendarViewMode.Day;
            viewModePicker.SelectedIndexChanged += ViewModeChanged;
        }

        private void ViewModeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
     calendar.TrySetViewMode((CalendarViewMode)viewModePicker.SelectedItem);
        }

        private void CalendarLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
     calendar.TrySetViewMode((CalendarViewMode)viewModePicker.SelectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```

`StartPage.xaml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:telerikInput="clr-namespace:Telerik.XamarinForms.Input;assembly=Telerik.XamarinForms.Input"
         x:Class="TelerikXamarinApp1.StartPage">

    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackLayout Padding="5">
                <Label Text="Select a view mode" />
                <Picker x:Name="viewModePicker" />
            </StackLayout>
            <telerikInput:RadCalendar x:Name="calendar" NativeControlLoaded="CalendarLoaded" Grid.Row="1" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: It looked like you didnt have the `telerikInput` added to your xaml file. Also it is hard to diagnose why `its just not showing up`. Have a look at the xamarin logs or device logs to see if theres an indicator as to why

Comment: But that exact combo of xaml and codebehind worked for me so I thought I would post it and see if you have different results